# open an activity by clicking on text hyperlink in android

Tags: android

I want to create a text hyperlink link "[Help](http://help)"

So that when someone clicks on this text an action can be taken on it. Like in my case a new activity will be opened.

Can someone help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this:

[Android: Launch activity from clickable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025770/android-launch-activity-from-clickable-text)

Answer (score 2):

Rishi,

See this answer here: [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

It shows you how to use `<intent-filter>` elements in your AndroidManifest to make your App respond to clicks on a particular URL.