# View a Large number of Tiled Images

Tags: android, image, scroll

**Note** : Everytime i mention an image, you can assume it's located on a remote server.

We have a large image that's too big to display on a mobile device, so we broke it into tiles (MxN).

I need a way to display these tiles on the screen and allow the user to smoothly scroll over them. I cannot store all the tiles in memory at once, i can store upto 9 (3x3 tiles).

Basically, i need to replicate how Google Maps loads images, downloading the tile only if the region is visible to the user, and stitch it up with its neighbors...

Need anything relevant on this topic...

**Edit**: I forgot to mention, using a webview is not an option since we need to do a little drawing over the images once they are retrieved.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: can you explain a bit, what kind of 'little drawing" you need to do?

Comment: I need to draw a push pin or a photo on the tiles.

Comment: can't you already draw them on the web-page? and then just use javascript interface to call some methods in your app. here is an example, not really exact one, but showing the idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453102/clickable-words-in-a-textview/5662697#5662697

Answer (score 1):

you can look at [source of osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/), they did something like this and probably it will help you.

Maybe i'm wrong, but another possibility could be to create a web page and show it in the webview.