# Linkify the text problem

Tags: android, linkify

It is a glossary application.I have kept the data in string-array ..in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="title">
    <item>aaaa</item>
    <item>bbbb</item>
    <item>cccc</item>
    <item>dddd </item>

</string-array>

 <string-array name="definition">
    <item>This is first entry relate to bbbb. .</item>
    <item>This is a book.</item>
    <item>This is  aaaa so link it there.</item>
    <item>This is related to cccc</item>

</string-array>
```

In activity1, I have list of all data displaying in a list view. On click of that it will go to activity 2 containing word and definition. In an activity2 I have 2 textviews.One for displaying title and second one for definition. In the definition,if any title exists it should be hyperlinked and onclick of that it should show the title and definition.

I followed the link below to refer..
    [Android: Launch activity from clickable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025770/android-launch-activity-from-clickable-text)

but in above question it is just a string..how to do for string array?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the Android Developer documentation is for [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).  Please read the documentation!!!

```
public static final void addLinks (TextView text, Pattern pattern, String scheme)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the title as parameter in the URL if you using PHP or ASP. Or make your one view with a webview passing the title to the other activity.