# How to add "[more...]" at end of text in android app

Tags: android, textview

I am creating an app in android and I am parsing text. After I parse the text, the text appears fine. However, I don't want all of the text to appear (i.e. all lines to appear together).

Example - 
Text that appears in app: 
A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules.

What I want to show: 
A Turing machine is a device that manipulates [more...].

So when the user taps on the [more...], the rest of the text will appear in a new window.

How do I incorporate the "[more...]" part?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

declare in your text view properties in the layout file

```
android:ellipsize="true"
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:singleLine = "true"` and

fix the width of your textview like `android:layout_width = "150dp"`, then append [more...] at the end of text and make it as link, which should be clickable

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026303/892055), to do what you want...

Comment: Thanks mA! =) This is exactly what I wanted to do. =d