# How can I make clicking on list view goto WebView instead of browser?

Tags: android

I have a ListView with tweets that have urls in them.  I want the user to stay in my app when they click on the links.  Direct them to a webview to display the url when they click on the url.  Can Linkify be used to redirect not the url, but the processing of the url to a Webview?

Comment: create an intent and start your Activity with the nested webview, as easy as that!

Comment: you have to use webViewClient class..

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things. One is to modify `Linkify` to support launching your own `Activity`. Or you could write your own regex to match those links and create clickable spans in your text to achieve it.

The second approach is presented here: [Android: Launch activity from clickable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025770/android-launch-activity-from-clickable-text/4026303#4026303)

Comment: This looks good, however, in creating the Spans, how would I know which indexes have the embedded text?

Comment: Why would you need indexes? These spans are clickable, so you can pass whatever you want (index, uri) to `onClick()`