# Setting clickable string - Textview (Android)

Tags: android, textview

My code looks like this,

```
String content = "Hi this is @Naveen. I'll meet @Peter in the evening.. Would you like to join @Sam??";

TextView contentTextView=(TextView)userHeader.findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
contentTextView.setText(content);
```

Before setting the text in the textview, I would like to add click event for @Naveen, @Peter and @Sam.. When the user taps on these texts I want to open a new intent.. Is that possible? Any pointers would be quite helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025770/android-launch-activity-from-clickable-text

Comment: @Daniel Yeaah saw that earlier.. but I couldn't understand :(

Comment: mmm... try to look into Linkify see docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) with custom patterns.

However, if that doesn't suit your needs you can try this:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hi this is @Naveen. I'll meet @Peter in the evening.. Would you like to join @Sam??");
ClickableSpan clickableSpanNaveen = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //Do Stuff for naveen
    }
};
ClickableSpan clickableSpanPeter = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //Do Stuff for peter
    }
};
ClickableSpan clickableSpanSam = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //Do Stuff for sam
    }
};

ss.setSpan(clickableSpanNaveen, 11, 17, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(clickableSpanPeter, 29, 35, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(clickableSpanSam, 76, 79, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TextView contentTextView=(TextView)userHeader.findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
contentTextView.setText(ss);
contentTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Leon.. I made a few changes in the code and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Linkify` class, which provides methods for adding links to `TextViews`. You can use the `addLinks(TextView textView, Pattern pattern, String scheme)` method, which needs you to specify the `TextView`, a `Pattern` for the text you want to match and a custom scheme that will be used to match `Activities` that can work with this kind of data. The `Activity` that you want to be opened when clicking on links must declare this scheme in its `intent-filter`. Hope this helps.