# Start activity from linked TextView

Tags: android, textview, deep-linking

How to start an `activity` from linked `TextView`. Here is my string which I set to `TextView`:

```
<string name="register">Do not have an account ? <a href="com.myapp://register"><b>Sign Up</b></a>.</string>
```

In the `manifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".Activites.RegisterViewPagerActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="com.myapp://register" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I start the `RegisterViewPagerActivity` activity from that string ?

P.S. I want to implement the logic inside the `AndroidManifest`, not in java class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Launch activity from clickable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025770/android-launch-activity-from-clickable-text)

Comment: it is not, since I want to organize it from the Manifest, not by coding.

Comment: `scheme` should probably only `myapp` without the register part, register is host

Comment: So it should be only: <data android:scheme="com.myapp" /> , am I right ?

Comment: This one also does not work:
                <data 
                    android:scheme="com.connectto.sleepapnea://"
                    android:host="register"/>