# Javascript interaction with Android's Webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, webview, jquery-mobile

I would like to get JavaScript to trigger an android event through a `webview`/`WebChromeClient` where the android device (can be potentially offline) would send the form back to the server. (I'm using jQuery mobile)

I'm thinking that to handle the offline issue I will have to save the form data to an XML file to submit at a later date.

How do I go about doing this? If it's even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Need to call an activity back from javascript interface made for WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312639/need-to-call-an-activity-back-from-javascript-interface-made-for-webview/5313515#5313515)