# Unable to call a new Activity from Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I trying to call a new Activity from my Webview. However, whenever i click on the specified `<div>` nothing happens. Please see my implementation below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://.../hello.html");
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void newActivityCalled(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewAct.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**hello.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#yoyo").click(function (){
        Android.newActivityCalled();
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="yoyo"> New Activity Text </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have not done this yet but **i think** u r missing **onClick** attribute

Comment: @SrinathGanesh i am calling the jquery onclick function $.click

Comment: [see whole](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5313515/1897935)

Comment: looks small code ill try this soon

Comment: why you have not wrapped this code within `doc ready` block?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason jQuery onclick method does not work. However, if you switch over to pure javascript then the code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function loadActivity(){
       Android.newActivityCalled();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="yoyo" onclick="loadActivity()"> New Activity Text </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so any jQuery working ? or jquery all commands fail in android ?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh i haven't had a good experience using jQuery when calling methods in Android. E.g. i wanted to capture a url in webview and do somethin using shouldOverideUrlLoading() method but wasn't able to do so if the HTML was wrapped in jQuery. That too worked fine in pure HTML or javascript

Comment: am not much comfortable with UI stuff , but a jQuery hello world check will help seeing if anything is working