# Android webview select change don't work before 4.4.x

Tags: javascript, android, webview

The webview in fragment doesn't invoke select javascipt fucntion change() before android 4.4.x. The system browser can do it.But the webview in the Activity can invoke.Please help me.

mi_fragment_tab_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tanliani.fragment.TabHomeFragment" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mi_tab_test_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TabTestFragment.java

```
public class TabTestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = TabTestFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private View view;
    private WebView mCurrentWebView;
    private HashMap<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Context context;

    public static TabTestFragment newInstance() {
        TabTestFragment fragment = new TabTestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public TabTestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "onCreate :: savedInstanceState = " + savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.mi_fragment_tab_test, container, false);
        mCurrentWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.mi_tab_test_webview);
        WebSettings setting = mCurrentWebView.getSettings();
        setting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setting.setUserAgentString("Mi-Android");
        mCurrentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mCurrentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        additionalHttpHeaders.put("unique_id", DeviceUtils.getIMEI(context));
        additionalHttpHeaders.put("ApiKey", "76b86bbd");

        // mCurrentWebView.loadUrl(CommonDefine.MI_H5_MEMBERS_SEARCH);
        mCurrentWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/select.html");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Logger.i(TAG, "onResume :: ");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Logger.i(TAG, "onPause :: ");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Logger.i(TAG, "onStop :: ");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

select.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>测试select</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="province" id="search-province">
            <option value="">地区不限</option>
            <option value="1">北京</option>
            <option value="2">河南</option>
            <option value="3">广西</option>
            <option value="4">山东</option>
            <option value="5">青海</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="6">江西</option>
            <option value="7">湖北</option>
            <option value="8">西藏</option>
            <option value="9">新疆</option>
            <option value="10">四川</option>
            <option value="12">湖南</option>
            <option value="13">内蒙古</option>
            <option value="14">上海</option>
            <option value="15">浙江</option>
            <option value="16">重庆</option>
            <option value="17">海南</option>
            <option value="18">河北</option>
            <option value="19">吉林</option>
            <option value="20">江苏</option>
            <option value="21">贵州</option>
            <option value="23">黑龙江</option>
            <option value="24">山西</option>
            <option value="25">甘肃</option>
            <option value="26">辽宁</option>
            <option value="27">天津</option>
            <option value="28">广东</option>
            <option value="29">宁夏</option>
            <option value="30">陕西</option>
            <option value="32">福建</option>
            <option value="33">安徽</option>
            <option value="34">云南</option>
        </select>
        <script>
        //选择地区
        $("#search-province").change(function () {
            var province = $("#search-province").find("option:selected").text();
            alert(province);
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fragment in FragmentTabHost

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Logger.i(TAG, "onCreate :: savedInstanceState = " + savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mi_activity_main);
    context = this;

    // View
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, mFragmentManager, android.R.id.tabcontent);
    TabWidget mTabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        mTabWidget.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
    }

    ...

    // Test
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_Test).setIndicator(
                    newTabItem(R.drawable.mi_selector_tab_search,
                            R.string.mi_navi_title_search)),
            TabTestFragment.class, null);

    ...
    }
```

---

You can download demo from here [WebViewDemo](https://github.com/tustar/WebViewDemo.git)

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312639/need-to-call-an-activity-back-from-javascript-interface-made-for-webview/5313515#5313515

Comment: @jmar777  Thanks! This can't solve my question. I don't want call system browser.